# How can I recovery my Ubuntu after I delete a directory using rm -rf by mistake?

Tags: login, data-recovery

I have deleted my total Torch (environment used for machine learning) directory using `rm -rf` by mistake, then I found that I can not get root by using `su ***`, and it said that I deleted `torch/install/bin/torch-activate`.

Then when I reboot my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I found I can not log in my administrator account. It said the same problem. I want to know, how can I recovery my deleted directory or how can I recovery my Ubuntu system without installing it again and losing all my old data?
I cannot get into the system now.

[image: the problem when I tried to log into my Ubuntu]

Comment: " I found I can not log in my administrator account" Does it mean `su ***`?
Did you try to recreate the torch/install/bin/torch-activate dir ?

Comment: Can you escalate to root by doing `sudo su`?

Comment: sorry, I mean I cannot escalate to root by doing ‘sudo su’, not 'su ***'.I wrote it wrongly.

Comment: @ZihaoLi - can you get into root using `sudo bash`?

Comment: By the way, [there's never a good reason to run `sudo su`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222). Just run `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` to get a root shell.

Comment: @Yaron No,I can not even enter the system now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a line in your `~/.profile` file that is attempting to read files that you've deleted. Just open `~/.profile` and delete the offending lines and you will be able to log in.

The error message is telling you that the problem is on lines 30 and 33 of `~/.profile`, which try to read `/home/lizihao/torch/install/bin/torch-activate`. So just delete those two lines.

Comment: But how can I modify that profile? I cannot enter the system as administrator now because of the problem.

Comment: @ZihaoLi drop to a tty (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`) and log in there, then `nano ~/.profile` and delete the lines. Then go back to the GUI with `Alt`+`F7`.